# Has SE invented a voting time machine?

Tags: bug, timeline

I just downvoted this question https://superuser.com/questions/1048123/read-only-wont-go-away-in-file-properties (screenshot in case it gets deleted):

[image]

However, when I go to the timeline, it shows that my vote happened 14 hours ago. The question was only asked 2 hours ago:

[image]

Has SE invented a voting time machine?

Comment: It's a daily summary, it doesn't have time. It should show "N/A" (or just stay empty) instead of the time.